Trouble removing tub spout
I am trying to replace some of my shower hardware with a new kit I brought at the re-store. Unfortunately, running into real trouble trying to take the old spout off. It looks like (pardon the bad picture; edit: added some better? [I hope] pictures) it should be a slip-on spout, though a set-screw is absent. I've also tried every imperial/metric hex key I have in there, just in case this is some whacky fastener, to no avail). However, like some other posts on here that I've read, the spout doesn't seem to want to be screwed off either, and I'm apprehensive about the prospect of damaging plumbing further into the wall.
I guess my questions are: does anyone have an intuition of what kind of spout im dealing with (it's made by jacuzzi if that's informative), and/or have suggestions for how to get it off safely?




Will need a good eyeball picture to tell if screw has been rounded off.  It looks like hex shape, or seeing things.  If it is rounded off, drilling is usual answer.

Tried to get some better pictures for you, if the new two are helpful

You need the top side of the screw to look like the bottom to have any chance for a hex key turning it.  Nice six sharp corners are needed.

A bit embarrassing, but to our surprise/relief, it was a screw-on spout. We just weren't twisting hard enough. Once that was off, we were able to get at the Allen wrench socket.

Twisting hard enough is quite close to not enough and too much.  Most plumbing twisting should be done with two wrenches, one to hold against the twist.
